# Superscripting a variable in R

Tags: r, variables, plot, superscript

I am a beginner in R and I am trying to put an equation that includes superscript variable on a plot. I know how to print superscript letters on the plot but I cannot figure out a way to insert a variable. Here are my codes:

```
DF <- data.frame(X <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Y <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1))

# Logistic regression
model <- glm(Y ~ X, family = binomial, data = DF)

# Plot raw data
raw_plot <- plot(DF$X, DF$Y,
        xlab = 'X', ylab = 'Y'
        )

# Add prediction curve
curve(predict(model, data.frame(X = x), type = 'response'), add = TRUE)

# Get coefficients
intercept <- summary(model)$coefficients[1] # -4.361418
coefficient <- summary(model)$coefficients[2] # 1.250679

superscript.part <- sprintf('%.2f + %.2f*x', intercept, coefficient)

text(5, 0.2, labels = expression(paste('y = 1/(1 + 1/e'^'superscript.part'*')')))
# This will superscript 'superscript' and not the actual variable
```

And this is what I get.

[image]

Is there a way to actually make the content of the variable printed out in superscript? Thank you for any help!

Comment: You can just do it like this if you have to `text(5, 0.2, labels = expression(paste(y = 1/(1 + 1/e^{-4.36 + 1.25*x}))))`

Comment: I like `substitute` as i find it easier to remember (then `bquot`e and `expression`) : `text(5, 0.2, labels = substitute("y = 1/(1 + 1/e" ^X *")", list(X=superscript.part)))`

Comment: Thank you! I read about substitute but could not get it to work but your example worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

`text(5,.2, bquote("y = 1/(1 + 1/e" ^~{.(superscript.part)} ~ ")"))`

Comment: I think this gives slightly nicer typesetting.. `text(5,.5, bquote(y == 1/(1 + 1/e ^~.(superscript.part))))` but????

Comment: Thank you! Both of them worked and gave me what I wanted. People here are really helpful and responds to me quickly and for a beginner like me, it is really helpful!